# FB._https not working for https

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

hello I am having problem related to `https://`. I have used `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)` function in my code. It is only working for `http://` but not for `https://`. I have googled it and found a solution of using `FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");`. It was working well few days ago but has now stopped working.

My code looks like

```
 <script>
        FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
        FB.init({
            appId : '<?php echo $this->appId; ?>',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml : true // parse XFBML
        });

     function PostAction(custom_action)
     {
        console.log('out side of getlogin status');
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
        {
          console.log("in getlogin status");
          if (response.authResponse) {
             fbcallBack(response);
          } else {
             FB.login(fbcallBack, {scope:'publish_stream'});
        }
      });
   }
</script>
```

My `PostAction()` is called on an onclick event. I have written `console.log()` to debugg the code. console with `out side of reglogin status` is triggered but not `in getlogin status` when using facebook with `https`. But if I am using `http://` it works well.

Can any body guide me please what is the problem? how to fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of yesterday at 22:00 Facebook made this announcement:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

> As announced in May, we have updated the Javascript SDK to limit the
>   publicly exposed interface. This is part of an ongoing process to
>   improve the reliability of the SDK. We have removed access to all
>   internal properties and to methods prefixed with _.
>
> If you are currently relying on accessing internal properties, please
>   refactor this so that you only rely on the publicly available (and
>   officially supported) methods listed at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/.
>
> Note that all methods not listed as part of the public API might be
>   subject to change or removal, and you should not use them directly.

Comment: I notice you do not have a channel file? I am not sure if that will help but it cannot hurt to try. Also why do you not get the login status BEFORE the user presses the button? I personally feel this is a better separation of concerns, as when the button is pressed you should already know the user's state.

Comment: dude I need to get login to button press.

Comment: OK, if the user is already logged in and connected to your app why would you want to show the login button? You should decide if they are  logged in at the start when the page first loads, then use listeners if the auth change elsewhere (E.G. user logs out of FB). You would put 'FB.getLoginStatus' in the additional FB init section. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: I am not using facebook login button. I am using some action verbs of facebook to have my own custom buttons.

Comment: This conversation straying off topic and I am reluctant to continue, I have answered your question above and suggested a possible fix in my first comment.